# Auto-Transformer: how to understand the following diagram?

Tags: wiring, lamp, electronic-ballast, ballast, autotransformer

I have a question about the CW Auto-Transfomer that I will be using. [image]

The wiring diagram is above. As you can see, the equitment takes 277/240/208/120V as input. But on its specification sheets, it never specify the output voltage. Can I assume that regardless of input level, the output voltage (which supplies to the cap and the lamp) will always be the same?

Comment: I believe the output voltage is specified by "OCV 270-330V", where OCV stands for Open Circuit Voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If you applied 277 volts to the top-tap of the primary or instead applied 120V to the bottom tap, the voltage seen at the secondary tap point should be the same. In fact the secondary wouldn't know whether it was supplied from any of the primary taps because they should all be designed to produce the same voltage at the secondary tap point.

If, on the other hand you decided to put 100 volts on the top-tap you couldn't expect the correct secondary voltage to be generated.

Comment: Yes, they have different wires for different voltage input level. So the thing is to apply the right voltage to the right input wires.

Answer (score 0):

The core flux depends on and is proportional to the primary voltage per turn .The diagram shows the number of primary winding turns are higher for 277 input voltage than the number of turns for 100 input voltage . So it is designed to keep the voltage per turn at the input side constant.This will mean that the output voltage will be approximately constant ....................
The open circuit ans short circuit currents are different for different input voltages.That will decide the power output of the lamp ..............................The input ratings (120*4=480;208*2.3=478.4 ;240*2=480;277*1.75=484.75 ) shows the input VA is almost constant .So it is designed for a constant power output (400w) lamp.